# GPS Code not working in iPhone os 3.1

Tags: iphone

I am Using the following code to get the user current location in iPhone o 3.1
but the application get crash.Did the code change in 3.1?

```
CLLocationManager  *locmanager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locmanager  setDelegate:self]; 
        [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];    
        [locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 0):

is self comforming to CLLocationManagerDelegate ?